# Nginx if condition

Tags: cookies, nginx

I am trying to removed all cookies from response headers if Pragma: no-cache is not present in the headers in Nginx.
I am trying to achieve this as below

```
if ( $sent_http_pragma !~* "no-cache"){ more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie*";
                                         break; }
if ( $sent_http_cache_control !~* "no-cache"){ more_clear_headers "Set-Cookie*";
                                         break; }
```

The if condition here fails and the cookies are cleared for everything, even if the condition is not satisifed, but the header is present.
Also tried using map as

```
 map $sent_http_pragma $pval{
            "~.* no-cache" 1;
 }
 map $sent_http_cache_control $ccval{
            "~.* no-cache" 1;
 }
```

but always getting default blank value.
Appreciate any help in this regards.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Experts, appreciate your help regarding this issue